# How can I display an image using Springboot-Thymeleaf

Tags: java, mysql, spring, image, spring-data-jpa

I am new to Spring boot, and I am trying to display an image from mySQL (Blob) using thymeleaf, saving to the database as a byte array was no problem, however I am having trouble on how to display it on my html page how should I go about this? Im trying to display the images on the home page

My Entity Class

```html
@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "post")
    private String text;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "img")
    private byte[] image;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,
                        CascadeType.MERGE,
                        CascadeType.PERSIST,
                        CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private Category category;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public byte[] getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(byte[] image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", text='" + text + '\'' +
                ", image=" + Arrays.toString(image) +
                ", category=" + category +
                '}';
    }
```

My Controller

```html
    @Autowired
    ItemService itemService;

    @Autowired
    CategoryService categoryService;

    @Autowired
    EmailSenderService senderService;

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String index(Model model){
        List<Item> headwearItems = itemService.findAllHeadwear();

        model.addAttribute("clothes", headwearItems);
        return "index";
    }
```

Html file attempting to display it

```html
    <div class="category-1">
        <h2>Headwear</h2>
        <div class="image-container" th:each="clothing : ${clothes}">
            <img th:src="${clothing.image}">
        </div>

    </div>
```

Result is a blank image Icon

Link to github repository https://github.com/crisncris0000/BeginnerSideWork/tree/main/ShoppingSite

Comment: The 2nd or 3rd answer from this post might help you. They use different approaches but both could work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48235379/how-to-display-byte-array-from-a-model-in-thymeleaf,

Comment: I tried doing that it wasn't displaying sadly