# Duplicate - How can I display an image using Springboot-Thymeleaf

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I've been trying to display an image using thymeleaf for awhile and having issues with it saving it as a byte array was no problem, however displaying it is extremely (for me at least) I followed a post with the question that was asked about it and had no results sadly, was hoping someone could help me with this problem

Controller trying to display the image

```
@GetMapping("/home")
public String index(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("clothingItems", itemService.findAll());
    return "index";
}

@GetMapping("/display/image/{id}")
public void displayItemImage(@PathVariable int id, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{

    response.setContentType("image/*");

    Item item = itemService.findItemById(id);

    InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(item.getImage());
    IOUtils.copy(is, response.getOutputStream());
}
```

My Entity class

```
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "post")
    private String text;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "img")
    private byte[] image;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,
                        CascadeType.MERGE,
                        CascadeType.PERSIST,
                        CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private Category category;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public byte[] getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(byte[] image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }
```

Trying to display it with thymeleaf

```
<div class="category-1">
    <h2>Headwear</h2>
    <div class="image-container" th:each="clothing : ${clothingItems}">
        <img th:src="@{'display/image/' + @{clothing.image}}">
    </div>

</div>
```

[image: Result]

I tried following this post [How to display byte array from a model in Thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48235379/how-to-display-byte-array-from-a-model-in-thymeleaf) and ended up with an empty image

im also getting a NumberFormatException when I try to open the empty image in a new tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your thymeleaf template for the code

```html
<img th:src="@{'display/image/' + @{clothing.image}}">
```

The `src` should point to `@{'/display/image/'}` you need to insert '/' that specifies you are referring to the root of your application also instead of `@{clothing.image}` it should be `${clothing.image}` as it's a variable, not a link.

So the above line code of should be

```html
<img th:src="@{'/display/image/' + ${clothing.id}}">
```

Try this in your `displayItemImage` method it's not advisable to directly write the content to the `response` entity and also change the MIME-TYPE to `image/png` or `image/jpeg`. Here's a better approach.

```java
   @GetMapping("/display/image/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<byte[]> displayItemImage(@PathVariable int id) {
        Item item = itemService.findItemById(id);
        byte[] image = item.getImage();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(image, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

For testing the method I have used H2 database. Here's the test code with the results.

```java
@SpringBootTest
class ShoppingSiteApplicationTests {
    @Autowired
    ItemService itemService;


    @Autowired
    private UserController yourController;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;




    @Test
    void testMethod() throws Exception {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(yourController).build();
        byte [] mockByte = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03};
        Item item = new Item();
        item.setImage(mockByte);

        itemService.saveItem(item);
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(get("/display/image/" + item.getId()))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG))
                .andReturn();

        byte[] responseBody = result.getResponse().getContentAsByteArray();
        assertArrayEquals(item.getImage(), responseBody);
    }
}
```

[image: Test Results]

Here's the live result from your [Github Repository](https://github.com/crisncris0000/BeginnerSideWork/tree/main/ShoppingSite) you can see the image displayed. The problem may be in the `MYSQL` setup or so, if yes please raise another question with the code. Hope it helps

[image: Live image]

Comment: thanks for letting me know about that did change it, however the image is still a blank

Comment: have you tried both suggestions? if yes then try printing the `id` to the console in the `displayItemImage` method to check it is being received on the server side. Also for extra debug open your browser console it should shay someting link `404 http://localhost:8080/display/image/{id} not found` error

Comment: Its displaying the id of images, as for that it would try and download a file

Comment: Also set the content type header to a valid MIME-type `image/*` is not a valid one. Set something like `image/png` or `image/jpeg`. Also, it's not a good practice to return void and write to the response Entity, but do these step and then we can see if the problem persists.

Comment: Switched it to png

Comment: still the same problem? Also check that `itemService.findItemById(id)` is not `null`. I am gonna provide you with an alternative approach if the problem persists.

Comment: I have a check in case the item would be null ill link the github repository if it will help https://github.com/crisncris0000/BeginnerSideWork/tree/main/ShoppingSite

Comment: I have edited the approach try it out meanwhile I test out your code..

Comment: Tried it image is still blank

Comment: Just to clarify your server-side code is fine. There isn't any error in that. I have tested both the one that I provided and the one you gave with the modification of `content-type`.

Comment: Alright, could it be im using the wrong datatype from mysql?

Comment: I am sorry but the approach provided is correct. I have tested the code live from your GitHub repository. I am going to update the answer with the results. Just to mention the problem may be in MySQL. I am using H2 in-memory for testing.

Comment: If its mysql should I be switching databases? if so which one would work best in my case

Comment: Alright will ask another about mysql thank you

Comment: Well generally I am not a database expert or so, but for testing, you can easily replace any database connection that's the benefit of using spring JPA. For testing H2 is fine. I don't see any problem with MYSQL if you can setup it up well for the project.